# Regex pattern selecting all characters and numbers after specific number until whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have created a regex pattern that selects a word after a specific word

```
$string = "Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 19:27:30 +0100 Subject: pastik4567"
$pattern = '/(?<=\bSubject:\s)([a-zA-Z-]+)/';
preg_match($pattern,$file,$subjectname);
print_r($subjectname);
```

result is just **pastik** not **pastik4567** so i`ve tried this

```
$string = "Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 19:27:30 +0100 Subject: pastik4567"
$pattern = '/(?<=\bSubject:\s)([a-zA-Z-]+[0-9]+)/';
preg_match($pattern,$file,$subjectname);
print_r($subjectname);
```

Now it selects **pastik4567** but if subject is, for example, **pastik** it does not select anything because the pattern wants to match numbers, too.

So I want to ask how to make this pattern "flexible" so that it returns **pastik** and **pastik4567**, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the ranges into 1 character class:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\bSubject:\s)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/';
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD6oK0/1)

Note that I placed - at the end of the character class, so that it is treated as a literal hyphen, not a range specifier.